# Java unit testing, get more data from assertion in loop

Tags: java, unit-testing, assertions

I'm doing a unit test on a network service that returns hundreds of products.
During my test today, one of this products is missing a field.

Because one product is missing a field my assertion fails (succeeds at finding the error, so it depends on how you see it), but what I want to know is which product is the one having the issue.

Here's my assertion code:

```
for (Catalog catalog : mCatalogs.catalogs) {
    if (catalog.products != null && !catalog.products.isEmpty())
    {
        for (Product product : catalog.products) {
            assertNotNull(product.sku);
            assertNotNull(product.title);
            assertNotNull(product.localeName);
            assertNotNull(product.description);
            assertNotNull(product.fullImage);
            assertNotNull(product.statusCode);
        }
    }
}
```

one of the products does not have the field `localName`

Is there a way to output to the command line a string with something like

`"product " + product.title + " failed"` ?

If so, how?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, calls that make an assertion in JUnit are overloaded to have an option to create an error message in case of failure.  In this case, call [the overload of `assertNotNull` that takes 2 parameters](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertNotNull(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)), the first being the error message.

```
assertNotNull("product " + product.title + " failed", product.localeName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Every assert* method has a version that takes a String as a first parameter, that is the string shown if the assertion fails.

```
assertNotNull("product " + product.title + " failed",product.localeName);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, using `assert` operator:

```
assert product.localeName != null : "product must have a local name";
```